# How do I add a method to a PASSWORD CLASS That checks for Validity

Tags: dart

I created a class called password, and I tried passing a method to it that checks if the password entered is up to 8 characters which would decide its validity, please help

I tried creating a method inside the class called isValid and then calling it in the main function but that caused even more errors in my code

My code snippet below;

```
import 'dart:math'; 
import 'dart:core'; 
import 'dart:io'; 

void main(){ 
final myOwn = Password(); 
myOwn.value = stdin.readLineSync()!; 
print(myOwn); 
} 

class Password { 
String value = ''; 
Password(){ this.value = value; } 

toJson() { 
print('Your password is $value');
} 

@override String toString() {
return 'Your password is $value';
}

}
```

Comment: Please add your current code

Comment: import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:io';

 
  

main(){
  final myOwn = Password();
  myOwn.value = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  print(myOwn);
  
  
  
  
  
  
  }
  
  
class Password{
  String value = '';
  
  Password(){
    this.value = value;
  }
  
  toJson(){
     print('Your password is $value');
  }
  
  @override
  String toString(){
    return 'Your password is $value';
  }
}

Comment: Hi Chibueze not on the comment section, I meant by editing your question and adding it. But thanks, I am waiting on the editing queue to update your question.

Comment: Sorry didn't see it earlier , it's approved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method the will evaluate the stored `value` and return whether the value meets the program expectations. It would return `true` if it is a good password or `false` if it is not good.

```dart
class Password {
  bool isValid() => value.length > 8;
  String value = '';
}

void main() {
  final password = Password();
  password.value = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  print(password.isValid());
}
```

Comment: I edited the code just the way you stated above but got the following error
class 2.dart:8:16: Error: Member not found: 'Password.isValid'.
print(Password.isValid());
               ^^^^^^^
Process finished with exit code 254.

Comment: This is it
import 'dart:math'; 
import 'dart:core'; 
import 'dart:io'; 

void main(){ 
final myOwn = Password(); 
myOwn.value = stdin.readLineSync()!; 
print(Password.isValid());
} 

class Password { 
bool isValid() => value.length > 8;
String value = ''; 
Password(){ this.value = value; } 

toJson() { 
print('Your password is $value');
} 

@override String toString() {
return 'Your password is $value';
}

}

Comment: The above code I shared is complete. It has no compile issues.

Comment: True true , I just discovered my mistake , thanks alot brother , you just solved my week long issue .

Comment: All this while I had actually been trying to add an if statement to the class Password lol , I guess it doesn't work that way